# Is there a way to drag and create while in shading tab?

Tags: texturing, materials

I've been doing some material work lateley and it feels kind of unpractical that I can't just drag and create a new node and then connect it. Am I somehow missing a shortcut to drag and create a node or is it just not possible?

Comment: If you create a node group, then it will appear in the Add>>Group menu in the Shader editor so you can reuse it.

Comment: The Node Wrangler addon (included in blender download but not enabled by default) may have some tools you find helpful.